# In how many ways can you make a necklace with $n$ black beads and $m$ white beads?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of different necklaces using $m$ red and $n$ white pebbles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204110/number-of-different-necklaces-using-m-red-and-n-white-pebbles)

I don't understand high level maths. Please try to do simple$\ldots$  I tried to hunt down the pattern but couldn't complete as I have my exam.

Comment: There is no reason to cripple your post below twitter message length or the like. So please use complete words.

Comment: Are you familiar with Burnside's lemma? The only way I see to do it is with that, but I don't know if you know Burnside's lemma.

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean "necklace" in the technical sense of considering arrangements related by a rotation as equivalent, as mentioned in sdcvvc's comment under Jen-Ya's answer, or in the everyday sense where a necklace has a distinguished spot where it opens and closes, so that rotations do matter.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** *Sorry, I was not aware that necklaces are considered equivalent up to rotation. Thanks to sdcvvc for correcting*

This solution is only right for situations, where rotations are not equivalent:

`(n+m)! / (n! * m!)`

You have `n+m` Beads and `(n+m)!` ways to order them.
But you have to ignore the order of black beads and the order of white beads.
There are `n!` permutations (possibilities to order) of black beads and `m!` permutations of white beads.
So you have `(n+m)! / (n! * m!)` ways to order the beads.

Comment: Necklaces are usually considered equivalent up to rotation, so this answer overcounts.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of that! Thanks for correcting.